# Ignore 1st option from multiple select box-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have multiple select box with same options which are mutually exclusive .For example if select box A and select box B  has option1 ,option2 and option 3 , Then if I select option1 for select box A, then it should not be available on select box B

My demonstration

```
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
        <option selected disabled>Select below</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
        <option value="4">option4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select" class="alert_type">
        <option selected disabled>Select below</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
        <option value="4">option4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select" class="alert_type">
        <option selected disabled>Select below</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
        <option value="4">option4</option>
    </select>

 $('.alert_type').change(function() { 
                           var selected_value=$(this).val();
                          $(".alert_type option[value='" + selected_value + "']").not(this.selectedOptions[0]).hide();

                          });
```

But I want to make 1st option as exception i.e  `<option value="">Select below</option>` as I need flexibility to revert all the option

**You can see on fiddle below , if I select option1 from select box 1 ,"select below" from option 3 is also removed which I want to put in exception**
Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/timus2001/rbuyk7na/3/

When I try with

```
$(".alert_type option").show();
```

to show all at first it is not mutually exclusive any more (see the picture)
[image]

Comment: Should `option` remain set to `display:none`?

Comment: yea , they are hidden but not deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. let me see if I get you this time:

```js
 $('.alert_type').change(function() { 
 var selected_values = [],
    iteration;
  $(".alert_type option").show();
  $(".alert_type").each(function(){
   iteration = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    if ( iteration !== "" ) {
     selected_values.push( iteration );
    }  
  })
  for ( var i = 0; i < selected_values.length; i++ ) {
   $(".alert_type option[value='"+ selected_values[i] +"']").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
        <option selected>Select below</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
        <option value="4">option4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select" class="alert_type">
        <option selected>Select below</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
        <option value="4">option4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select" class="alert_type">
        <option selected>Select below</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
        <option value="4">option4</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: if I add $(".alert_type option").show(); then the option wont be mutually exclusive anymore ... I also thought this  at first

Comment: What do you mean with mutually exclusive? how does that translate into the frontend?

Comment: No , it wont help . I  must be able to  select  "slelect below " too so that I can edit my selections

Comment: then remove your disable attribute from the html, I removed it in my answer and works fine

Answer (score 0):

### This is what you need:

```js
$('select.alert_type').on('change keyup',function() {
 var val = $(this).val();
 $('select.alert_type option').prop('disabled',false);
 $(this).siblings().find('option[value='+val+']').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" class="alert_type">
        <option selected disabled>Select below</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
        <option value="4">option4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select" class="alert_type">
        <option selected disabled>Select below</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
        <option value="4">option4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select" class="alert_type">
        <option selected disabled>Select below</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
        <option value="4">option4</option>
    </select>
```

Good luck :D